# Number of Islands problem. BFS solution is slow, trying to figure out the bottlenecks

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an m x n 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), return the number of islands.

An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

My solution:

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        no = 0 # number of islands
        visited = set()
        rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])

        def visit(row, col):
            if (row, col) in visited or grid[row][col] != "1": return False

            q = deque()
            q.append((row, col))

            while q:
                row, col = q.popleft()
                if (row, col) in visited or grid[row][col] != "1": continue

                visited.add((row, col))

                # Visit left
                if col > 0:
                    q.append((row, col - 1))

                # Visit right
                if col < cols - 1: 
                    q.append((row, col + 1))

                # Visit top
                if row > 0:
                    q.append((row - 1, col))

                # Visit bottom
                if row < rows - 1: 
                    q.append((row + 1, col))

            return True

        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                if visit(row, col):
                    no += 1
        return no
```

It only beats ~40% solutions so there's clearly something that can be improved. What is it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is because of the visited set you're maintaining. That can easily be removed, since you can edit the matrix in-place to keep a track of visited nodes.

1. Removing the set would lower the time, since no more insert/delete/lookup operations for the set
2. You can just number the nodes. Like mark all nodes in the first island with -1, nodes in the second island with -2, etc. Removes the set and makes it much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to classify different islands with different numbers. Since you only care if the `grid[row][col]` is "1", after you visit each island, just turn them to "0"s so you won't visit them again.

from typing import List
from collections import deque

class Solution:
def **init**(self):
self._directions=[[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]]

```
def numIslands(self,grid:List[List[int]])->int:
        ROWS,COLS=len(grid),len(grid[0])
        count=0

        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                if grid[row][col]=="1":
                    count+=1
                    stack=deque()
                    stack.append([row,col])
                   # I found the first "1", I added to queue, and then make its value "0"
                    grid[row][col]="0"
                   # stack keeps all "1"s in the same island
                    while len(stack):
                        current=stack.popleft()
                        current_row=current[0]
                        current_col=current[1]
                        for direction in self._directions:
                            new_row=current_row+direction[0]
                            new_col=current_col+direction[1]
                            if new_row<0 or new_row>=ROWS or new_col<0 or new_col>=COLS:
                                continue
                            if grid[new_row][new_col]=="1":
                                stack.append([new_row,new_col])
                                # I found another "1" in the same island, push it to stack and make its value "0"
                                grid[new_row][new_col]="0"
        return count
```